# Formal way of expressing something (like a job) done for someone

Tags: formality

I'm looking for a formal way (as in a CV) to express something done for a particular client, for example:

*(I've) developed websites for Clients X and Y*

The only form that comes to mind is ～のために, but that doesn't sound formal to me, especially in the context of a CV.

Comment: I think its fine, but it would be more helpful if you gave us a look at the full attempt for your sentence, since formality will derive a lot from the other words you use as well.

Comment: @ajsmart I was thinking something along the lines of "A社とB社の為、ウェブサイト開発。" since it would be part of a list in a western style CV. However I'm interested in more general answers to the above question, as opposed to just finding other ways to translate that particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

履歴書の「制作実績」の欄などに、箇条書きで書くのなら・・・

> X社・Y社**の**Webサイト(を)制作

のように、「の」を使えばよいと思います。 (「を」は省略していいです。）

Comment: 履歴書の書き方を紹介してるページをいろいろ見ると、一つの案件ごとにもっと詳しく書くみたいですけど。例えば　https://mynavi-agent.jp/prepare/creative_02.html